# Dynamically SELECT columns based on column name and date reference

Tags: mysql

Our Table currently looks like this:

Record ID | Name | ... | Value_2301 | Value_2302 | Value_2303| ...

Where 2301, 2302 and 2303 are dates in YY-MM format. Due to the nature of our system, as the years go by, the table will continue to grow wider as more columns are added (eg. Value_2401, Value_2402). This isn't the best of practices but I don't think we will be changing this practice any time soon.

We would like a query which retrieves only Values that are dated 1 year back and 1 year in advance (so since we are in year 2023, the columns to retrieve are Value_2201 to Value_2412), without hardcoding any years.

My initial idea is to use the following syntax:

```
select CONCAT('Value_', CONCAT(right(year(current_date())-1,2), '01')); -- returns Value_2201
select CONCAT('Value_', CONCAT(right(year(current_date())-1,2), '02')); -- returns Value_2202
...
select CONCAT('Value_', CONCAT(right(year(current_date()),2), '01')); -- returns Value_2301
...
select CONCAT('Value_', CONCAT(right(year(current_date()) + 1, 2), '12')) -- returns Value_2412
```

to create a dynamic list of column names that we would like to retrieve. Ideally, I would like to somehow fit this list into the query so that the query will always retrieve Value columns that are within 1 year back and 1 year in advance, but I am at lost of how to do so, or if it even is feasible.

Would greatly appreciate any help and feedback from you guys.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dynamic columns names needs in dynamic SQL. I recommend you  to create according stored procedure and call it providing needed parameters into. If the output should be used in another queries then use intermediate temptable with some predefined name.

Comment: I'd be fascinated to know how you ended up with this design?
How many columns does your table currently have?  How many rows?  What type are the columns

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility of creating & executing dynamic SQLs in MySQL.

```
SET @qStr = (
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT Value_', CONCAT(RIGHT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())-1,2), '01'), ' FROM tbl')
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @qStr;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here, the variable `@qStr` will be a string having the following value in it as on today:
`SELECT Value_2201 FROM tbl`

Here, `Value_2201` will be dynamically added based on the date.
You can create any complex query like this.

And then,

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @qStr;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

These two will prepare an executable statement from that string and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

This expands on Ishan's answer, using the `information_schema` to provide the list of column names:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        'SELECT id, name, ',
        GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION),
        ' FROM ' ,
        TABLE_NAME
    ) INTO @qStr
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test'
AND COLUMN_NAME BETWEEN CONCAT('Value_', DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, '%y01'))
                    AND CONCAT('Value_', DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 YEAR, '%y12'))
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;

PREPARE stmt FROM @qStr;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```